# Azure Pipeline Timeout issue

Tags: azure-pipelines

Azure build pipeline times out after 60 minutes.
As to Release pipelines, I have seen them running for longer than an hour - does the same 60 minute time-out rules not apply to Releases?

Also, is it possible to create Release pipeline through yaml?

Comment: In YAML, there's no such thing as "build" or "release" pipelines. If you use environments and deployment jobs in a pipeline, it's a "release" pipeline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Pipelines task timeout not respected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59748634/azure-pipelines-task-timeout-not-respected)

Comment: @DanielMann When I create a Pipeline from my yaml through "Repo > Setup Build > Create from Existing Pipeline", it times out at 60 minutes. But when I create a Release pipeline and add the steps from the Editor, it runs for longer (~1 minute and 10 minutes) and eventually succeeds

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to create Release pipeline through yaml?

In the [2018 Q4 Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline), MS release the CD for the YAML by the Multi-stage YAML pipelines:

> To accomplish this, we now offer a unified YAML experience, so you can
> configure each of your pipelines to do CI, CD, or CI and CD together.
> Defining your pipelines using YAML documents allows you to check the
> configuration of your CI/CD into source control together with your
> application’s code, for easy management, versioning, and control.

The following is copied and pasted from the article and demonstrates using various stages:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
    continueOnError: true
    steps:
    - script: echo my first build job
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
    # track deployments on the environment
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
    # creates an environment if it doesn’t exist
    environment: 'smarthotel-dev'
    strategy:
      # default deployment strategy
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo my first deployment
```

Note: For the timeout for the pipeline, we could set `timeoutInMinutes: xx`:

```
jobs:
- job: Test
  timeoutInMinutes: 10 # how long to run the job before automatically cancelling
  cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 2 # how much time to give 'run always even if cancelled tasks' before stopping them
```

You could refer the document [Timeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#timeouts) for some more details.